# get object of array of objects with exact key

Tags: php

```
Array
    (
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [position] => 1
                [priority] => 1
                [percentage] => 100
            )
        [131] => stdClass Object
            (
                [position] => 11
                [priority] => 12
                [percentage] => 80
            )


    )
```

this is my array of objects.

Why I cant get object with like this: $a = $niz[1] ?

Comment: That looks fine to me. Can you do `var_dump($a)` (or `var_dump($niz[1])`) and post the result?

Comment: You can - what errors are you getting

Comment: Message: Undefined offset: 1 this is error. It is very strange

Comment: Please vardump/print_r the complete $niz variable. Maybe you have missed some level of nesting

Comment: `array (size=3)
  '21' => 
    object(stdClass)[36]
      public 'position' => string '21' (length=2)
      public 'priority' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'percentage' => string '100' (length=3)
  '51' => 
    object(stdClass)[37]
      public 'position' => string '51' (length=2)
      public 'priority' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'percentage' => string '80' (length=2)
  '11' => 
    object(stdClass)[38]
      public 'position' => string '11' (length=2)
      public 'priority' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'percentage' => string '60' (length=2)` this is var_dump

Comment: OK, so echo $niz[21]->percentage; should output 100, i dont see the problem

Comment: Yes but $niz[21]->percentage gives me again the error Message: Undefined offset: 21

Comment: This is bizaare. It should work fine. Can you recreate the problem with a small test case - eg small enough to paste the whole code so others can run it and see the problem? Otherwise it seems like a localized issue

Comment: it is wamp bugging, I uploaded on server and everything is working fine also ksort doesnt work on wamp - windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the stdClass object to php array so you can access it by normal way.

```
$niz = get_object_vars($niz);
$a = $niz[1];

print_r($a);
```